# How to format long lines of argument description in Google docstring style

Tags: python, styles, args, docstring

This is an excerpt from a Google style docstring:

```
def function_with_types_in_docstring(param1, param2):
    """Example function with types documented in the docstring.

    `PEP 484`_ type annotations are supported. If attribute, parameter, and
    return types are annotated according to `PEP 484`_, they do not need to be
    included in the docstring:

    Args:
        param1 (int): The first parameter.
        param2 (str): The second parameter.

    Returns:
        bool: The return value. True for success, False otherwise.

    .. _PEP 484:
        https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/

    """
```

How do I format the args in case the description spans a line ?

Answer (score 9):

When the description spans more than one line, you can break the line and indent. In your example:

```
"""
`PEP 484`_ type annotations are supported. If attribute, parameter, and
return types are annotated according to `PEP 484`_, they do not need to be
included in the docstring:

Args:
    param1 (int): A really long description of the first parameter that
        spans more than one line. If you've got a really long description
        you can continue to break the line where you want, indent and 
        continue describing your parameter
    param2 (str): The second parameter.

Returns:
    bool: The return value. True for success, False otherwise.

.. _PEP 484:
    https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/

"""
```

This keeps the docstring readable and the line length short. It also preserves the formatting if you are exporting to [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/index.html).

This is the recommended method in the [Google Python Style Guide](http://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#doc-function-args)

> List each parameter by name. A description should follow the name, and be separated by a colon and a space. **If the description is too long to fit on a single 80-character line, use a hanging indent of 2 or 4 spaces (be consistent with the rest of the file).**
>   The description should include required type(s) if the code does not contain a corresponding type annotation...